# Exoplayer - InvalidResponseCodeException (404) while file exists

Tags: android, exception, subtitle, http-response-codes, exoplayer

I am working on Exoplayer Demo to use it in my application. Everything works well except subtitles. I use Expression Encoder 4 pro to encode movies to II Smooth Streaming format. When I add English subtitle to the movie, Exoplayer shows eng-subtitles correctly but when I add Persian subtitle to the movie, Exoplayer throw an InvalidResponseCodeException.
I am sure that the url is correct since I can download it by the browser.

http://www.test.com/XXX/QualityLevels(546)/Fragments(textstream_fas=0)

```
com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 404
        at com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:204)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.DefaultUriDataSource.open(DefaultUriDataSource.java:87)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer.chunk.ContainerMediaChunk.load(ContainerMediaChunk.java:146)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:242)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Is there something special that I should know about it?
Let me know if you need additional information.

**Edit:**
When I open the Fragments(textstream_fas=0).* in notepad++, it shows the file is encoded in ANSI.

Thanks

Comment: Similar issue here. Any luck with the solution?

Comment: I have similar issue but not with sub, with whole video. Any solutions ?